# How to install DraftSight on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu on my laptop. I downloaded DraftSight and tried to install it via terminal using this commands I found online:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libdirectfb-extra libxcb-render-util0
sudo dpkg --force-all -i ~/Downloads/draftSight.deb
sudo apt-get -f
```

It said some package is missing and offered to replace it with other packages which I did. I found icon but when I try to run Draft this message pops: "Failed to load modules. The application will close.Please reinstall the application." When I try to uninstall it, it says it can't be done because it's not installed.

I'm not to familiar with Ubuntu, I have just started using it. Can someone please tell me how to fix this, I need this programme for my lectures and I don't want to give up using Ubuntu.

Comment: Please find help in this link: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/easily-install-draftsight-64-bit-ubuntu/ Works for me. Hopefully for everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. This seems to solve it:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386
```

Comment: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 and libcanberra-gtk0:i386 are not in the Ubuntu repositories. Did these two files come from a PPA? Please add information to your answer about the software sources of libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 and libcanberra-gtk0:i386.

Answer (score 0):

Try gdebi, it will download the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi

sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/draftSight.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the same message pops when I try to run it: "Failed to load modules. The application will close. Please reinstall the application." Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the .deb file

```
#!/bin/sh

## Fix a DraftSight Debian package to make it installable on a 64bit machine.

## Last known realease is http://dl-ak.solidworks.com/nonsecure/draftsight/V1R4.0/draftSight.deb

ORIGINAL=draftSight.deb
PACKAGE=fixed-$ORIGINAL

if ! test -f $ORIGINAL
then
echo "$ORIGINAL file does not exist."
PACKAGE=$(zenity –file-selection –filename=draftSight.deb –file-filter=deb)
fi

echo "Copying $ORIGINAL into $PACKAGE"
cp $ORIGINAL $PACKAGE || exit 5;

echo "Extracting control.tar.gz"
ar x $PACKAGE control.tar.gz || exit 5;

echo "Unpacking control.tar.gz into control directory"
mkdir --parents control || exit 5;
tar -zxf control.tar.gz --directory control || exit 5;
mv control.tar.gz control.tar.gz.orig

echo "Removing wrong dependency (xdg-utils)"
if sed -in-place -e "s/ xdg-utils,//" control/control
then
  echo "Repacking contents of ‘control’ directory into control.tar.gz"
  (cd control; tar --create --file ../control.tar *) || exit 5;
  gzip --best --no-name control.tar
  echo "Storing patched control.tar.gz back into $PACKAGE";
  ar r $PACKAGE control.tar.gz || exit 5;
  echo "Draftsight original package $ORIGINAL patched into $PACKAGE"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For 16.04 and Draftsight 2016:

In terminal `cd /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/`.

Run HelpGuide with `./HelpGuide` and look for the dependency errors.

`apt-get` the missing dependencies.

I was missing `libgstreamer0.10` and plugin package.

Comment: I was also missing this package, but installing it manually did not fix the problem. Installed using `sudo apt install libgstreamer0.10-0`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio